# outlook add in add tabs in runtime

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I using vs 2013  .NET 4.5.1  c#

how can I add tabs to outlook ribbon in runtime?

I try :

```
        Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonTab OneNewTab;
        OneNewTab = this.Factory.CreateRibbonTab();
        OneNewTab.SuspendLayout();

        OneNewTab.Label = "newtab";
        OneNewTab.Name = "newtab;
        this.Tabs.Add(OneNewTab);
```

but I Get :

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.Implementation.dll but was not handled
>   in user code Additional information: Collection is read only. Cannot
>   change content of the collection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add tabs at design time and make them visible and run-time.

Answer (score 1):

The Ribbon UI is a static thing. You can't add new tab on your own at runtime.

The Fluent UI extensibility model is based on the [IRibbonExtensibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonextensibility.aspx) interface. The host application calls the [GetCustomUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonextensibility.getcustomui.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method implemented in your add-in to get the custom UI markup. So, you can't do so at runtime.

As a workaround you can define the getVisible callback and call the IRibbonUI.Invalidate or IRibbonUI.InvalidateControl methods to force the host application refresh the UI.

Read more about the Ribbon UI (aka Fluent UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)